# windows-fido-bridge cmake error

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, openssh

I'm building the windows-fido-bridge here: https://github.com/mgbowen/windows-fido-bridge from source, but running into an error on line `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..`. The error reads:

```
-- Executing inside WSL: ON
-- Executing inside Win32: OFF
-- Executing inside Cygwin: OFF
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:33 (message):
  Unrecognized OpenSSH security key API version "10"
```

Any idea what's going wrong? I'm running WSL Ubuntu 22.04 jammy and OpenSSH 8.9